# XPath for anchor in sibling TD

Tags: xml, xpath

I am tying to work out the XPath to select the A tag in the 2nd sibling TD from the one that matches "Paypal Sale". There are many such rows on the table so wanting to get the first match.

Here's my HTML

```
 <tr>
   <td class="ref">Paypal Sale</td>
   <td class="icon">...</td>
   <td class="from"><a class="nav" href="http://google.com">Click here</a></td>
 </tr>
 ...
 <tr>
   <td class="ref">Paypal Sale</td>
   <td class="icon">...</td>
   <td class="from"><a class="nav" href="http://google.com">Click here</a></td>
 </tr>
```

So far I have this but not working:

```
//tr[td=\'Paypal Sale\'][1]/following-sibling::td[2]/a
```

Comment: tr/following-sibling::td returns nothing because there are no td siblings of tr element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//tr/td[. = 'Paypal Sale']/following-sibling::td[2]/a
```